# Storing Android base64 public key on a server

Tags: android

After reading several questions (like [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33686/strong-encryption-for-base64-encoded-public-key-in-android), [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5564/how-to-secure-android-market-public-key) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671865/how-to-protect-google-play-public-key-when-doing-inapp-billing)) about storing the Android base64 public key for an android application, it seems that storing the key on a server, and retrieving it using needed by using HTTPS is a good way to go about it.

Are there any tutorials which show how to do this? I am not sure about how to setup a server, and then how to contact it from my application for the key when required.

Comment: Do you need to store it on a server? Why not just hardcode in your app?

Comment: Yes, I can hardcode it in my app, and obfuscate it. But as per the many answers provided like http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33686/strong-encryption-for-base64-encoded-public-key-in-android, to store it on a server seems to be the best way.